# Export an SQL Stored Procedure as input / output with data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

I would like to document the stored procedures in an efficient way. Something like that:

**SP Name:**

Get_Emp_Info

**Input:**

EmpID INT

**Output:**

DataSet 1:

- Status char
- StatusMessage varchar(100)

DataSet 2:

- Email NVARCHAR(100)
- Name NVARCHAR(100),

How can I achieve this if SP has many joins and output is not always from one table?

Comment: "I would like to document the storage procedures in an efficient way" - why do you want to do this? Documentation derived from an implementation is not particularly useful (and makes it brittle and requires you update it every time the implementation definition changes) because it's easier just to look at the source-code.

Comment: @Dai, if i have this documentation, i can share it with the developer of the Web API and they can map the input / output to the required implementation in their side. I know that there are better approaches such as swagger but I am stuck with SPs for now that i didn't even create

Comment: Just give the developer the database schema (`CREATE TABLE...`) statements and the stored-procedure source-code - but they should be able to get that themselves anyway if they can connect to the database with SSMS. Just open SSMS > Database > Tasks > Generate Scripts, or generate a DACPAC file.

Comment: Better yet: use SSDT - that way your database design can be in source-control too and you can spin-up and populate test databases in seconds.

Comment: @Dai, thanks for the ideas and solutions. Scripting the storage procedure will not return the data types outputs of the SP. I have SSDT but it will also work on the table design not SP design.

Comment: What do you mean by "return the data-types output"?  Also, SSDT **does** support developing Stored Procedures - that's the main reason SSDT was created in the first place.

Comment: I meant the output datasets as the question indicate, the columns that returns and their data type

Comment: Then use `SET FMTONLY ON`, see here: https://www.sqlshack.com/see-schema-result-set-running-query/

Comment: To document like you are asking there is no automatic way... you have to do it by hand. Its not clear to me how joins affect creating documentation?

Comment: Thus the question Dale, i was hoping that there is a quick solution that will capture the output, understand that this variable is coming from that table, and give me the data type of the column

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - its about the closest you can get that I know of.

Comment: That could never work. What about the situation, where an output value comes from no table at all, but is calculated with the sp from a combination of factors? How would such a tool ever be able to work out where it came from? Also I have seen plenty of sps that deliver different recordsets (with different types), according to input parameters - I hate them but they exist. To get what you want, you will need to do it yourself.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, You still need to declare those values with whatever type they are expected to be. This is all what i want, as you can see from my question. I don't need the table name exactly.

Comment: @DaleK,  sp_describe_first_result_set, this is excellent, i think this is a good start to what i need to do. Many thanks

Comment: @DaleK, Your solution worked Dale, it's excellent and simple. I can pass the execution of the SP with the input and get all the outputs of the first result set.Even declared and calculated values are returned. Could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual documentation I think you will have to write by hand.

However SQL Server does provide a tool, [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which may be helpful in obtaining the definition of the output result for use by your documentation